# "Property not found" with PrimeFaces RemoteCommand

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to update a Prime Faces [PickList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf) with a [RemoteCommnad](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) and I'm getting a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'updatePermissions' not found` exception when the `updatePermission` property is defined.

This is my UI definition file:

```
<h:form>

              ...           

            <h:selectOneMenu id="groupsList" value="#{permissionsToGroupsBean.selectedGroup}" title="Select Group" onclick="updatePermissions()">
                <f:selectItems value="#{permissionsToGroupsBean.allGroups}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

              ....              

            <p:pickList 
                id="permissions" 
                value="#{permissionsToGroupsBean.permissionsPickList}" 
                var="permissionsPickList" 
                itemLabel="#{permissionsPickList}" 
                itemValue="#{permissionsPickList}" />

            ....

        </h:panelGrid>      

        <p:remoteCommand name="updatePermissions" actionListener="#{permissionsToGroupsBean.updatePermissions}" update="permissions"/>
```

This the controller that is supposed to handle the UI:

```
public class PermissionsToGroupsBean implements Serializable {

    ...

    public void updatePermissions() {
        getPermissionsPickList().setTarget(getPermissionsForSelectedGroup());
    }
}
```

When I access the page URL I get:

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'updatePermissions' not found on type tld.company.admin.web.bean.PermissionsToGroupsBean
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:193)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:170)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:279)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:60)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:118)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:214)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:155)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CommentInstruction.write(CommentInstruction.java:77)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)`

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it ... the problem was that Prime Faces doesn't handle comments for some reason ...

I had a commented out action listener defined under the one I posted in the question:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updatePermissions" actionListener="#{permissionsToGroupsBean.updatePermissions}" update="permissions"/>

        <!-- <p:remoteCommand name="updatePermissions" update="permissions">  
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{selectedPermissions}" target="#{permissionsToGroupsBean.updatePermissions}" />  
        </p:remoteCommand>  -->
```

As soon as I removed it it worked.

A signature with `void` return type and no parameters works:

```
public void updatePermissions() {
    getPermissionsPickList().setTarget(getPermissionsForSelectedGroup());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`actionListener="#{permissionsToGroupsBean.updatePermissions}"` I`m not familiar with the current version of PrimeFaces but generally the`actionListener`property would be expected to return an object that implements the`ActionListener`interface. Thus your expression would be resolved to`getUpdatePermissions()` which doesn't exist and thus you get that message.

If you added that method you should see that there's another problem with the return value not being an `ActionListener`.

Does the `<p:remoteCommand>` tag support an `action` property instead?

Comment: Yes it does support it. It should be possible to do it without the property also however as per the prime faces documentation. Also in this question you can see it done without the action listener property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367689/jquery-primefaces-remotecommand-parameter-issue.

Comment: I also tried with the `get` method prefix. I get the same error.

Comment: @Simeon The question you linked just states this: `actionListener="#{bookmarklet.loadImages}"` which means the `loadImages` property would define the ActionListener (there's no source linked for that method, thus I can only make assumptions here). That you get the same error for the renamed method might indicate that actually, the resolver looks for a method of name `getUpdatePerissions()` with return type `ActionListener` (or a subclass). Since that method would not have such a return type, the resolver would still not find it.

Answer (score 1):

updatePermissions(ActionEvent e) ?